# Assigning du values to array

Tags: bash

I'm creating a function that gets an unspecified number of file names in input and returns an array with the size of all the files.
I'm using `du` to check the file size, but I'm not sure on how to assign every file size to a different element of the array.
What I've done so far (not working)

```
for i in size
do
size[i]=$(du -h "$@")
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

size=($(du -h "$@" | awk '{ print $1 }'))
echo ${size[@]}
```

Sample call:

```
./script.sh config README.md
```

Sample output:

```
12M 4,0K
```